# how to compute hash string for sms retriever API in IONIC v4

Tags: ionic4, sms-retriever-api

I'm implementing Auto OTP verification in Ionic 4 using ionic sms retriever plugin, and I am getting App hash string from getAppHash method for my sms template but its not working in release mode. So please suggest that how to solve this problem.
And also I need to compute App Hash from command line, how it works?

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

download this file
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/bin/sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh

and run command

```
./sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh --package yourPackageName --keystore your_keystore_file_location
```